# Automatically deploy SPFx app on new site collections in SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, spfx-extensions

I have SPFx app that contains an Application Customizer. I would like to have this app either
a) deployed tenant wide or
b) automatically added to a site collection when it is created

For a) there is the an option for [tenant wide deployment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/tenant-scoped-deployment), but [it does not seem to work for Application Customizers in SP2019](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/3590).

So, then only option b) is left. But how do you suggest accomplishing that? By using feature stapling and a feature event receiver that adds the app via SP ALM API or PnP CSOM? If yes, may I ask for an example? Especially, how to get the ClientContext for all kind of authentication options, e.g. ADFS.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you can add it to a site collection and it will be available automatically whenever a subsite is created, is that feasible for you ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it should work with site collections.